# ZPL code logic and barcodes which contain - symbol

Tags: barcode, zpl

I need to create a barcode that contains HYPHEN symbol and
the following value  is an example  211212-PB00000658

the ZPL code generated is

```
^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW1343
^LL406
^LS0
^BY4,3,91^FT316,199^BCN,,Y,N
^FH\^FD>;211212>6-PB>500000658^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

Can someone explain to me what this is >6-PB>5   and  what the logic behind is  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a character set change. Also notice the `>;` in the beginning, to start with `Subset C` (all numeric) instead of the default `Subset B`. It allows to reduce the barcode size. You may compare these 2, the resulting barcodes contain the same information but the not compressed one is wider.

```
^XA

^BY4,3,91
^FT26,190^BCN,,Y,N
^FD211212-PB00000658^FS

^BY4,3,91
^FT26,390^BCN,,Y,N
^FH^FD>;211212>6-PB>500000658^FS

^XZ
```

**Result:**

[image]

**From ZPL manual:**

> UCC/EAN-128 offers several advantages. It is one of the most complete,
> alphanumeric, one-dimensional symbologies available today. The use of
> three different character sets (A, B and C), facilitates the encoding
> of the full 128 ASCII character set. Code 128 is one of the most
> compact linear bar code symbologies. Character set C enables numeric
> data to be represented in a double density mode. In this mode, two
> digits are represented by only one symbol character saving valuable
> space. The code is concatenated. That means that multiple AIs and
> their fields may be combined into a single bar code. The code is also
> very reliable. Code 128 symbols use two independent self-checking
> features which improves printing and scanning reliability.

**Your barcode explanation:**

```
>;211212>6-PB>500000658

>;          start code C (all numeric)
211212      numeric value
>6          invocation code, select subset character code B, allowing alphanumeric
-PB         hyphen and PB characters
>5          invocation code, select subset character code C, all numeric again
00000658    numeric value
```

**Reference:** (see p.82 to 86)
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf